# What does "compare like with like" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "compare like with like" mean?

> Teenagers often compare themselves with pop or fashion icons, people we see on TV and so on. But they are not comparing like with like.

Comment: What search did you do?  This was the first Google hit. http://getitglossary.org/term/comparing+like+with+like